# PC "encountered a pr*blem and needs to restart" then "boot device not found"

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, boot, crash

About a minute after turning my computer on, it just shows a blue screen saying "Your PC encountered a problem and needs to restart". Then it either restarts, or more often, comes up with the message "Boot Device Not Found. Please install an operating system on your hard disk." (an HP message).

I don't have enough time to troubleshoot the problem as this happens over and over with only a minute or so with Windows booted up.

This has happened before but just went away. What caused the problem is unclear as I hadn't recently made any system changes (e.g. installing software).

Hardware and system info:

- Windows 10
- HP Envy laptop
- Dual boot with Ubuntu 14.04
- Ubuntu 16.04 subsystem installed
- Norton antivirus running

Please let me know in the comments if you need any more info. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Does Ubuntu 14.04 also fail if you boot into that?  If both Windows and Ubuntu fail then that would point to hardware as a possible issue.  If it's just Windows then that makes software more likely.

Comment: @headkase After a few minutes, parts of Ubuntu just stopped working, like the taskbar (note: this was already an issue, and it's why I switched back to Windows). I also checked out the Windows partition from Ubuntu, but it couldn't mount complaining of an unsafe state.

Comment: Are you using an SSD?  I had an SSD which was starting to fail (and did so at the start of the disk where boot info is stored), and it behaved in a similar way.   The weird thing was that ddrescue eventually managed to copy everything from the SSD.

Comment: @davidgo Yes it's an SSD. The laptop is only about a year old so would this be a likely scenario?

Comment: @iononja - Sorry, I don't know. It's not extremely likely - SSDs should last more then a year for typical use, but it will depend on a lot of factors, and I'd only be guessing. How big is the SSD, and what model?

Comment: Posting SMART info for the drive can't hurt - but my drive did not -even have a SMART failure!

Comment: @davidgo 256 GB. Having trouble finding the brand

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information — e.g., everything you’re already written as comments.  (Comments sometime go away.)  In particular, if you’ve been having failures with this PC *with **two different** operating systems,*  you should explain that ***in the question**.*

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like hard drive failure to me, but I am not experienced with SSDs which are supposed to be more durable than standard hard disks. It's my opinion that any hardware can fail no matter the age. Sometimes we just unluckily get a defective product.

My recommendation would be to immediately back up any important data to another drive, if you haven't done so already. It may also be possible to clone the entire drive to a new disk with a software such as [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) as long as the drive is in readable condition. Then you wouldn't need to do a fresh install of each OS on the new disk.

**Edit:** If you get a new disk & do a fresh install & the problem persists, then the issue may be with the mainboard. If you clone to a new disk & the problem persists, then it could be an issue with the mainboard, or it could simply be data corruption & you may need to do a filesystem repair or fresh install.

**Edit:** Have you tried using the *chkdsk* command within Windows? Windows 10 may have some newer utilities that I am not familiar with for checking & repairing the filesystem.